# filtering on a multivalue choice field in Report Builder

Tags: 2010, reporting-services

In my List I have a Choice column that allows for multiple values via checkbox. Using `Like` is the only way I have found that successfully filters.

[image]

Is there a better way?

Also, this does not work, unless I'm doing something wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the "In" operator and seperate the Values by a comma.

So

Expression: [PracticeGroupSecondary]
Operator: In
Value: Business, Reorganization, Bankruptcy